# Infinite sum for all valid triangles triples (a, b, c)

Tags: summation

Find the infinite sum of f(a, b, c) = ((2 / 5) ^ a) * ((11) ^ (-c)) * ((7 ^ (-a - b))

for ordered triples(a, b, c) such that a, b, c satisfy the triangle inequality. I simplified the input to a simpler formula given above but unable to approach further. Answer can be represented in the form p / q.
Here a, b, c must be positive integers.

I am unable to put this condition to calculate this sum.

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica or a math question?

Comment: I tried to simplify using Wolfram Mathematica but unable to code it as I don't know how to put in the triangle inequality. Ultimately I needed the answer, so I decided to code it out as I was unable to solve it analytically.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole):

```
Sum[
    ((2/5)^a)*((11)^(-c))*(7^(-a-b)) Boole[a<b<c && c<a+b],
    {a,Infinity},
    {b,Infinity},
    {c,Infinity}
]
```

> 1/1516743381

Answer (score 3):

```
 Sum[((2/5)^a)*(11^(-c))*(7^(-a - b)) ,
  {a, Infinity}, {b, a + 1, Infinity}, {c, b + 1, a + b - 1}]
```

> 1/1516743381

note this works for symbolic contstants..

```
Sum[p^a/q^c/ r^(a + b)  ,
 {a, Infinity}, {b, a + 1, Infinity}, {c, b + 1, a + b - 1}]
```

> p^2/((-1 + q r) (-p + q r^2) (-p + q^2 r^2))

```
% /. {p -> 2/5, q -> 11, r -> 7}
```

> 1/1516743381